# Error in outlook addin dialog. TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "context"

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-dialog-api

I am trying to create a [dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) in my outlook add-in. I got this error from the browser console of the dialog while loading office scripts. The dialog contains a simple html page with jquery and office scripts references in the header.

```
TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "context" outlook-web-16.01.js:19:9756

ObjectOrReflectDefineProperty self-hosted:1762
    defineProperty self-hosted:1813
    defineNondefaultProperty https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/outlook-web-16.01.js:19
    defineEnumerableProperty https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/outlook-web-16.01.js:19
    <anonymous> https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/outlook-web-16.01.js:19
```

This is the source code of the dialog page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sustainable Meeting Activated Successfully</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      (function () {
        console.info("Test Dialog");
        Office.initialize = (reason) => {
          $(document).ready(function () {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);
          });
        };
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include a single version of Office js.

Change

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```